# Getting null on reset password with Firebase in react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm getting null in response when hitting password reset function of firebase.

```
  //login with firebase
  const ForgotPasswordRequest = async () => {
    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const res = await auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(SignupDetails.email); //email is passing
      console.log(res); // getting null here
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      setIsLoading(false);
      if (error.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
        alert('That email address is already in use!');
      }

      if (error.code === 'auth/invalid-email') {
        alert('That email address is invalid!');
      }
      if (error.code === 'auth/user-not-found') {
        alert('There is no user record with this email!');
      }
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
```

these are the versions i'm using

```
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.2.1",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^14.2.1",
```

Update: This is happening on success response for the email exists in firebase. While on giving wrong email it is authenticating and giving error object.

Comment: It should be the default behavior to resolve in `null` value when promise succeed.

Comment: Yes, I should receive password reset email then. Used it a long time ago it returns a success object.